# jQuery Autocomplete box stays open and in same position when scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When the autocomplete textbox is expanded, and the user scrolls the browser page, the box stays in the same position and does not disappear.  I'm ok with it being open if it stays in the same position, but I don't understand why it's staying in the same spot on scroll.

```
function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.combobox", {
        _create: function () {
            var self = this,
                select = this.element.hide(),
                selected = select.children(":selected"),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
            var input = this.input = $("<input id='innertextbox'>")
                .insertAfter(select)
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                        response(select.children("option").map(function () {
                            var text = $(this).text();
                            if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                return {
                                    label: text.replace(
                new RegExp(
                "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }));
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        self._trigger("selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
                        if (jQuery(ui.item.option).hasClass('_self'))
                            window.location.href = ui.item.option.value;
                        else
                            window.open(ui.item.option.value,'_newtab');
                    },
                    change: function (event, ui) {
                        if (!ui.item) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                valid = false;
                            select.children("option").each(function () {
                                if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                                    this.selected = valid = true;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }); var innerBoxValue = $("#innertextbox").val(); 

                            if (!valid && innerBoxValue != "Daily Needs...")  {
                                // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                $(this).val("");
                                select.val("");
                                input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })

                .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content");

            input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
            };
            this.button = $("<button type='button' id='dailyNeedsButton'>&nbsp;</button>")
                .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                .insertAfter(input)
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                .addClass("ui-button-icon")
                .click(function () {
        jQuery("#innertextbox").val("");
                    // close if already visible
                    if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                        input.autocomplete("close");
                        return;
                    }
                    // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                    $(this).blur();
                    // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete("search", "");
                    input.focus();
                });

        },
        destroy: function () {
            this.input.remove();
            this.button.remove();
            this.element.show();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("#dailyNeedsSelect").combobox();
    jQuery("#innertextbox").blur(function () {
        jQuery("#innertextbox").val("Daily Needs...");
    });
    jQuery("#innertextbox").val("Daily Needs...");
    jQuery(".ui-autocomplete").position({ my: "right top", at: "right bottom", of: jQuery("#innertextbox"), collision: "flip flip" }); 

    jQuery("#dailyNeedsButton").blur(function () { jQuery("#innertextbox").val("Daily Needs..."); });
    jQuery("#innertextbox").focus(function () { if (jQuery("#innertextbox").val() == "Daily Needs...") jQuery("#innertextbox").val(""); });

    jQuery("#innertextbox").bind("click", function () {
        jQuery("#innertextbox").val("");
    });
});
```

Comment: Any links/jsfiddle/code you can provide? Question like this can't really be answered.

Comment: i added the code although it's not formatting correctly and i'm trying to fix this problem so i'm not spending time on that...

Comment: which `autocomplete plugin` you are using; there a a lots of outside. please mention the plugin link atleast

Comment: What do you mean by "it's staying in the same spot on scroll". You code is the same as the [demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox), when I scroll with the menu open, the menu stays attached to the textbox...

Comment: it wasn't working.  it was behaving as if the autocomplete box was absolute positioned.  this is also within a sharepoint context, so that may be what was gumming up the works.  what i did instead is bind to the scroll event and set the position every time the user scrolled.

Comment: @kav, can you please suggest you can get a solution for this problem or not? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Nivs - sorry for the delay in replying.  Did you see the solution below?  Does that work for you?  I can't remember what we did in this case.

Answer (score 6):

This has been fixed with the addition of the appendTo option for the autocomplete method:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#option-appendTo